# How to properly return a result from mysql with Node?

Tags: node.js

In the code

```
var stuff_i_want = '';
stuff_i_want = get_info(parm);
```

And the function get_info:

```
get_info(data){
      var sql = "SELECT a from b where info = data"
      connection.query(sql, function(err, results){
            if (err){ 
              throw err;
            }
            console.log(results[0].objid); // good
            stuff_i_want = results[0].objid;  // Scope is larger than function
            console.log(stuff_i_want); // Yep. Value assigned..
    }
```

in the larger scope

```
stuff_i_want = null
```

What am i missing regarding returning mysql data and assigning it to a variable?

============ New code per Alex suggestion

```
var parent_id = '';
    get_info(data, cb){
          var sql = "SELECT a from b where info = data"
          connection.query(sql, function(err, results){
                if (err){ 
                  throw err;
                }
                return cb(results[0].objid);  // Scope is larger than function
    }
```

==== New Code in Use

```
 get_data(parent_recording, function(result){ 
    parent_id = result;
    console.log("Parent ID: " + parent_id); // Data is delivered
  });
```

However

```
console.log("Parent ID: " + parent_id);
```

In the scope outside the function parent_id is null

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You're going to need to get your head around asynchronous calls and callbacks with javascript, this isn't C#, PHP, etc...

Here's an example using your code:

```
function get_info(data, callback){
      
      var sql = "SELECT a from b where info = data";

      connection.query(sql, function(err, results){
            if (err){ 
              throw err;
            }
            console.log(results[0].objid); // good
            stuff_i_want = results[0].objid;  // Scope is larger than function

            return callback(results[0].objid);
    })
}


//usage

var stuff_i_want = '';

 get_info(parm, function(result){
    stuff_i_want = result;

    //rest of your code goes in here
 });
```

When you call `get_info` this, in turn, calls connection.query, which takes a callback (that's what `function(err, results)` is
The scope is then passed to this callback, and so on.

Welcome to javascript callback hell...

It's easy when you get the hang of it, just takes a bit of getting used to, coming from something like C#

Comment: I can't assign to stuff_i_want from inside the callback of get_info. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37):

I guess what you really want to do here is returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object with the results. This way you can deal with the async operation of retrieving data from the DBMS: when you have the results, you make use of the Promise **resolve** function to somehow "return the value" / "resolve the promise".

Here's an example:

```
getEmployeeNames = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    connection.query(
        "SELECT Name, Surname FROM Employee", 
        function(err, rows){                                                
            if(rows === undefined){
                reject(new Error("Error rows is undefined"));
            }else{
                resolve(rows);
            }
        }
    )}
)}
```

On the caller side, you use the `then` function to manage fulfillment, and the `catch` function to manage rejection.

Here's an example that makes use of the code above:

```
getEmployeeNames()
.then(function(results){
  render(results)
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log("Promise rejection error: "+err);
})
```

At this point you can set up the view for your results (which are indeed returned as an array of objects):

```
render = function(results){ for (var i in results) console.log(results[i].Name) }
```

**Edit**
I'm adding a basic example on how to return HTML content with the results, which is a more typical scenario for Node. Just use the `then` function of the promise to set the HTTP response, and open your browser at http://localhost:3001

```
require('http').createServer( function(req, res){
if(req.method == 'GET'){
    if(req.url == '/'){
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        getEmployeeNames()
        .then(function(results){
          html = "<h2>"+results.length+" employees found</h2>"
          html += "<ul>"
          for (var i in results) html += "<li>" + results[i].Name + " " +results[i].Surname + "</li>";
          html += "</ul>"
          res.end(html);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          console.log("Promise rejection error: "+err);
          res.end("<h1>ERROR</h1>")
        })
    }
}
}).listen(3001)
```

Comment: Cool. I've done this with another script, but when I try to move from console.log of results to putting them in an array, I get nothing. What's the solution when I don't want it going to console?

Comment: @KenIngram you should post your code: what are you trying to do? The `render` function I posted gets the array as parameter, so `results` is your array of objects. If you print it directly you'll get something like `[ RowDataPacket { Name: 'James' },
  RowDataPacket { Name: 'Mary' } ]`. You can also access array properties like `results.length`.

Comment: I was able to get some help on the Promises. Now that I understand it, your example makes complete sense.

Comment: Look at this many moons later, I've had time to work with Promises and async/await. So your solution sinks in a lot more.

Comment: Considering my understanding at the time, this answer was too complicated for me to grasp the logic. I understand better now, and there is a much simpler way to explain what's happening in my question.

Answer (score 13):

Five years later, I understand asynchronous operations much better.
Also with the new syntax of async/await in ES6 I refactored this particular piece of code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2') // built-in promise functionality
const DB = process.env.DATABASE
const conn = mysql.createConnection(DB)

async function getInfo(data){
  var sql = "SELECT a from b where info = data"
  const results = await conn.promise().query(sql)
  return results[0]
}

module.exports = {
  getInfo
}
```

Then, where ever I need this data, I would wrap it in an async function, invoke `getInfo(data)` and use the results as needed.

Comment: Thanks, Easiest method to access data

Answer (score 1):

This was a situation where I was inserting new records to a child table and needed the prent record key, based only on a name.

This was a good example of understanding the asynchronous nature of node.

I needed to wrap the all the code affecting the child records inside the call to find the parent record id.

I was approaching this from a sequential (PHP, JAVA) perspective, which was all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Easier if you send in a promise to be resolved
e.g

```
function get_info(data, promise){

      var sql = "SELECT a from b where info = data";

      connection.query(sql, function(err, results){
            if (err){ 
              throw err;
            }
            console.log(results[0].objid); // good
            stuff_i_want = results[0].objid;  // Scope is larger than function
            promise.resolve(results[0].objid);
    }
}
```

This way Node.js will stay fast because it's busy doing other things while your promise is waiting to be resolved

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to implement Promises. I am stuck at converting the returned promise into usable data. I understand the concept, however, how to complete the technical implementation is eluding me.

Comment: db.findOne(272).then((user) => {
       console.log("Find user in location strategy", user[0]);
       return done(null, user[0]);
      }).catch(error => {
       return done(err);
      });

Comment: I keep looking at this. It's an answer, but it assumes I understand how to make sense of it. I figured out Promises, but his snippet never actually helped. I needed a simpler breakdown. Neurodiverse.

Comment: Just over 2 years later and this solution makes more sense to me. But I'm curious about the function signature. Are you saying to invoke the function like this : get_info(data, new Promise())? I'm thinking async/await may fit the bill at this point.

Comment: You're right it's an odd way to do it. get_data should just return the new promise itself then it could be chained. Like you I gained more experience with it as time went on.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this goal since few weeks, without any result, and I finally found a way to assign in a variable the result of any mysql query using await/async and promises.

You don't need to understand promises in order to use it, eh, I don't know how to use promises neither anyway

I'm doing it using a Model class for my database like this :

```
class DB {
    constructor(db) {
        this.db = db;
    }


    async getUsers() {
        let query = "SELECT * FROM asimov_users";
          return this.doQuery(query)
    }

    async getUserById(array) {
      let query = "SELECT * FROM asimov_users WHERE id = ?";
      return this.doQueryParams(query, array);
    }


    // CORE FUNCTIONS DON'T TOUCH
    async doQuery(queryToDo) {
        let pro = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            let query = queryToDo;
            this.db.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err; // GESTION D'ERREURS
                resolve(result);
            });
        })
        return pro.then((val) => {
            return val;
        })
    }
    async doQueryParams(queryToDo, array) {
      let pro = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let query = queryToDo;
        this.db.query(query, array, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err; // GESTION D'ERREURS
            resolve(result);
        });
      })
      return pro.then((val) => {
        return val;
      })
    }
}
```

Then, you need to instantiate your class by passing in parameter to constructor the `connection` variable given by mysql. After this, all you need to do is calling one of your class methods with an `await` before. With this, you can chain queries without worrying of scopes.

Example :

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let DBModel = new DB(connection);

    (async function() {
        let oneUser = await DBModel.getUserById([1]);
        let allUsers = await DBModel.getUsers();

        res.render("index.ejs", {oneUser : oneUser, allUsers : allUsers});
    })();

});
```

Notes :

- if you need to do another query, you just have to write a new method in your class and calling it in your code with an `await` inside an `async function`, just copy/paste a method and modify it
- there are two "core functions" in the class, `doQuery` and `doQueryParams`, the first one only takes a string as a parameter which basically is your mysql query. The second one is used for parameters in your query, it takes an array of values.
- it's relevant to notice that the return value of your methods will always be an **array of objects**, it means that you'll have to do `var[0]` if you do a query which returns only one row. In case of multiple rows, just loop on it.

Comment: This is an interesting implementation. Looks simple enough. I eventually found a solution that uses PHP and NODE, but I like the way you have done this. I understand async/Promises better now.

Comment: If you want to see this in a real app, take a look to the two files here https://github.com/Oskar-Ardolo/asimov/tree/master/core
Here, you can find how it gradually becames even more simple when the project is growing

Comment: Oh. I like this Vincent. It seems more elegant than I would have done. Great example.