# How to store Node mysql query in a variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using node mysql to connect to an external DB and I can `console.log` the query results but when I try to return the data I get `Promise pending`.

Here is the function -

```
export function get_info() {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'xxxxxx',
        user: 'bob',
        port: 'xxxx',
        password: 'bob',
        database: 'li_webform'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT Name FROM webform", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log(result); **This works**
            //console.log(result[0].Name);
            return result;
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to set a variable equal to the return value like this

```
var newVar = get_info();
console.log(newVar);
```

but I got the promise pending note. I believe this has something to do with the Asynchronous nature of JavaScript. I've tried following this post [How to properly return a result from mysql with Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875621/how-to-properly-return-a-result-from-mysql-with-node) but can't get it working.

Here is what I tried following that post

```
export function get_info(callback) {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'xxxxx',
        user: 'bob',
        port: 'xxxxxx',
        password: 'bob',
        database: 'li_webform'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT Name FROM webform", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log(result);
            //console.log(result[0].Name);
            return callback(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Then I try to use it via

```
var stuff_i_want = '';

get_info(function (result) {
    stuff_i_want = result;
    console.log(stuff_i_want);
});
```

But I get no output

Edit** Here is new attempt

```
export function get_info() {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'xxxx',
        user: 'bob',
        port: 'xxxxxx',
        password: 'bob',
        database: 'li_webform'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query("SELECT Name FROM webform", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            //console.log(result);
            //console.log(result[0].Name);
            return result;
        });
    });
}
```

and second part

```
    get_info().then((callbackData)=>{
   console.log("Data: ", callbackData)
 }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Error", error)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a promise. You can handle it like this:

```
 get_info().then((callbackData)=>{
   console.log("Data: ", callbackData)
 }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Error", error)
 });
```

Comment: I'm getting Data:  undefined. Do I still have the return statement in the get_info function?

Comment: Did you try first or second way?
for this to works you should use the first piece of code you wrote in the post.

Comment: I used the first way and I get Promise Object

Comment: With the solution i posted? That should works if the function returns a promise.

Comment: Yes, with solution you posted. I just updated my original post with the attempt. It results in data undefined. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can we try this: 

`export function get_info() {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'xxxx',
        user: 'bob',
        port: 'xxxxxx',
        password: 'bob',
        database: 'li_webform'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return connection.query("SELECT Name FROM webform");
    });
};`

Comment: Still getting undefined :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185449/discussion-between-fpolig01-and-jair-a-diaz-zambrano).