# How to store value from an sql query to a variable in node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using mysql with nodejs for the first time and I wish to enter the result from an sql query in my webpage through an asynchronous function. I am able to get the correct result but unable to store it within a variable and then use it as an input value.

[I've tried using this but this doesn't provide a viable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840186/how-to-store-node-mysql-query-in-a-variable). I tried returning the value as well. Also will it be advisable to process the query outside the async function or inside it?

```
(async function Ahmedabad() {  
      let i = 'select RegNumber from Details ORDER BY RegNumber DESC LIMIT 1;';
  await  con.query(i, [true], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.error(error.message);
    }
    let x = results[0].RegNumber;
    console.log(x);      // <------- Shows correct value
  });
  console.log(x);        // <------- Says x is not defined
})()
```

I want to store the value into a variable and then use it further.

Comment: "*I've tried using this but this doesn't provide a viable solution.*" Can you elaborate a bit as to why a near-exact duplicate of your question doesn't provide "a viable solution"?

Comment: Because there is only one answer to that question and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the statement "*doesn't work*"? It does point out the fact that the code should return a `Promise` object to be handled accordingly.

Comment: There is probably some error in the way the promises are handled in the answer provided, I keep getting "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `x` in the callback scope, so it's not accessible out of the callback.
Try this:

```
(async function Ahmedabad() {  
      let i = 'select RegNumber from Details ORDER BY RegNumber DESC LIMIT 1;';
  let x;
  await  con.query(i, [true], (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.error(error.message);
    }
    x = results[0].RegNumber;
    console.log(x);      // <------- Shows correct value
  });
  console.log(x);        // <------- Says x is not defined
})()
```

But to be honest you should think about the whole design of your code))