# Solved Why do MySQL statements work normally in Node REPL when typed line by line, but not in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-connector

I'm writing a reddit bot to scan all comments and write to a MySQL table every time any user writes a comment with a certain keyword, so the table keeps track of how many times any given user used the keyword. All of this works fine. The trouble came when I made a small website with NodeJS that lets you query the database. When I fire up a Node REPL session and I execute the following lines one at a time, things work great:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
data = [];
let db = mysql.createConnection({ // Log into the database
  host: "leHost",
  user: "leUserName",
  password: "leSuperSecurePassword",
  database: "reddit"
});

db.connect(function(err) { // connect to the database via our login
  db.query("SELECT * FROM nicecount", function(err, result, fields) { // Execute this statement
    data.push(result); // add each row that is returned to data[]
  });
});

console.log('returning this data:');
// Data is in the form of [['Username', value], ['Username', value]]
console.log(util.inspect(data));
db.end(); // Close the connection to the database
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
[
RowDataPacket { username: 'benjixinator', value: 3 },
RowDataPacket { username: 'SciNZ', value: 1 },
RowDataPacket { username: 'RetainedByLucifer', value: 1 },
RowDataPacket { username: 'marknielsen777', value: 1 }
]
```

But when I turn it into a function like so:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

function getUserData(username) {
  data = [];
  let db = mysql.createConnection({ // Log into the database
    host: "leHost",
    user: "leUserName",
    password: "leSuperSecurePassword",
    database: "reddit"
  });

  db.connect(function(err) { // connect to the database via our login
    db.query("SELECT * FROM nicecount", function(err, result, fields) { // Execute this statement
      data.push(result); // add each row that is returned to data[]
    });
  });

  console.log('returning this data:');
  // Data is in the form of [['Username', value], ['Username', value]]
  console.log(util.inspect(data));
  db.end(); // Close the connection to the database
  return data;
}
```

And then run it, I get the following:

```
> response = getUserData('benjixinator');
returning this data:
[]
[]
> response
[ undefined ]
```

I don't know why there are **two** empty brackets `[]`. I expect the output to be something like this:

```
> response = getUserData('benjixinator');
returning this data:
[
RowDataPacket { username: 'benjixinator', value: 3 },
RowDataPacket { username: 'SciNZ', value: 1 },
RowDataPacket { username: 'RetainedByLucifer', value: 1 },
RowDataPacket { username: 'marknielsen777', value: 1 }
]
> response
[RowDataPacket { username: 'benjixinator', value: 3 }, RowDataPacket { username: 'SciNZ', value: 1 }, etc...]
```

---

My two-part question:

1. Why is the result different when it's in a function?
2. How can I modify my code to have it return the MySQL data when run as a function?

---

## Edit: Solution

Using the answers from this question that @Shadow referred me to, [How to properly return a result from mysql with Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875621/how-to-properly-return-a-result-from-mysql-with-node), I was able to get this to work for me as follows:

The gist of the issue is that the database query is asynchronous, meaning that the result of the query is not put in the array by the time I'm accessing the array to check it for the result of the query. What to do? *If only there was a specific JavaScript feature made for issues just like this...*

Then, suddenly, **JavaScript ES6 Promises** enters the scene!

```
function getUserData(username ) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM nicecount WHERE username = ?', [username], (err, rows) => { 
      // The addition of the username bit was not part of the solution, it's just part of my project.
      if (rows == undefined) {
        reject(new Error('Error: rows is undefined.'));
      } else {
        resolve(rows);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

So now I have a function, `getUserData`, which queries the database and returns a promise. Then, I use this promise as such:

```
getUserData(req.body.username)
    .then(response => {
      data = [];
      for (let row of response) {
        data.push({
          username: row.username,
          value: row.value
          // ^ I am sure there is a more efficient way to do this,
          // please @ me in a comment with the answer...
        });
      }
      // Now, data[] has the results from the query,
      // and I can do whatever I want with them
      // from here to the end of this .then() block.
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
```

And that's how it's done! Thanks again to @Shadow!

Comment: Can you add which mysql package you are using? Probably https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql ?

Comment: @JoCa it's the 'mysql' package. I'm adding it to my code now, thanks

Comment: @Shadow Yup, that really helped me out. When I get a fully working version, I'll submit it and mark it as the answer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @benjixinator if the duplicate question helped you,  then rather than adding one more answer here, please accept that your question is a duplicate and up vote the answer in the duplicate question and perhaps the question as well.

Comment: @Shadow will do. Thanks for sending me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875621/how-to-properly-return-a-result-from-mysql-with-node) question!